# Transactions in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, transactions

i have 2 queries i want to execute inside a transaction
rollback

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "host",
    user: "user",
    password: "pass"
});
var query1 = "insert into table1 values (1,2,3)";
var query2 = "update last_update set date=now()";
connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } 
        connection.query(query1, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    connection.rollback(function() {
                        throw err;
                    });
                }
                });
        connection.query(query2, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    connection.rollback(function() {
                        throw err;
                    });
                }
                });           
  });
```

when i run this nothing happened no errors and the queries don't excecute

Comment: You have to provide a little more information than this for us to be able to help.

What packages are you using, how do the queries look?
Are you sure the queries are not fired? I dont see you doing anything with the result - so as long as there is no error, you will not be notified about anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you begin a transaction, you will also have to commit it - else, nothing will get updated.
You need to execute the following, but AFTER both queries ran:

```
connection.commit(function(err) {
    if (err) { 
      connection.rollback(function() {
        throw err;
      });
    }
    console.log('success!');
  });
```

To know when its AFTER both queries, you could either put the second query in the callback of the first, and the commit-query in the callback of the second - the problem is, that by this you enter the so called `callback-Hell` which makes your Code bascially unreadable.

How to avoid callback hell goes beyond the scope of this answer, but just have a look [here to read more about it](http://callbackhell.com/)

Comment: is there a way to rollback if the first query failed  i don't want to put my queries in callback

Comment: You can leave the error-handling with the rollback-function as it is. By throwing an error, the second query not gonna be executed anyways if the first fails.

Maybe also have a look into `async` for flow-control.